# Remove labels in gmap.net

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm building an application where I'm using gMap.net (not google maps). I need a totally physical map where there are no labels. All the mapProviders are showing labels. As in the attached picture you can see few landmarks are there. Is there any way to remove them.

[image: Screenshot of Form: Gmap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik the map data is provided as is, there's no option of actually peeking into the map layers delivered by the map providers.

If the satellite-only imagery is not an option, have you looked at either of those:

- ArcGIS_World_Physical_Map
- ArcGIS_World_Shaded_Relief_Map
- ArcGIS_World_Terrain_Base_Map

Depending on the zoom level these might be a neutral option.

Comment: ArcGIS_World has not the database for the whole world. Few tiles are missing. Can you suggest any other maps?